# When do we use Static and Dynamic class Loading?

Tags: java, class

I know the difference between Static class loading and Dynamic class loading.
In general,we always use Static class loading only.Can anyone tell, under which situations we use Dynamic class loading??

Comment: A good example may be a plugin loading system. Where plugins are loaded at runtime. Using reflection, you are able to load classes from external class files (normally packaged as jars) dynamically.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Dynamic Class Loading allows the loading of java code that is not known about before a program starts. The Java model loads classes as needed and need not know the name of all classes in a collection before any one of its classes can be loaded and run.

For example : 
Depending on user input you want to create only one object and there are hundreds of classes.
Then you don't need load all classes. You can create object at run time by dynamic class loading.

Code:

```
try {
    InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(in);

    System.out.println("Enter Class Name: ");
    String whatClass = reader.readLine();

    Class exampleClass = Class.forName(whatClass);
    Object ob = exampleClass.newInstance();

} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: > "Then you don't need load all classes" - 

This isn't actually unique to dynamic loading, since static class loading only happens on-demand, when the first object of that class is created. AFAIK dynamic loading is mostly used for things like the factory pattern, or to selectively run class initialization code.

Comment: Actually, that's the reflection mechanism？

Comment: What is "The Java model" by the way? @nilesh.b

Answer (score 13):

## DYNAMIC CLASS LOADING

It allows you to build your applications so that key external dependencies are not compiled into the application source-code.

### APPLICATIONS

#### JDBC

For example, in the JDBC case, it allows you to switch between different driver implementations, and (in theory) different database vendors without changing your source code.

#### PLUG-INS

Another use-case is when some supplier develops a generic form of an application with extension points that allow customers to "plug in" their own custom classes. The custom classes are typically loaded using Class.forName(...).

#### FRAMEWORKS AND CONTAINERS

A third use-case is application frameworks and containers which typically use Class.forName(...) under the hood to dynamically load the classes for application-specific beans, servlets, and so on.

#### OTHERS

A fourth use-case is where the application (or more likely an application library) has modules that are not used in a typical application run. By using Class.forName(...) internally, the application or library can avoid the CPU and memory overhead of loading and initializing large numbers of unwanted classes. (The Sun Swing libraries apparently do this to reduce application startup times, and I'm sure there are other examples.)

Refer [Dynamic Class Loading](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Reflection/Dynamic_Class_Loading)

Answer (score 4):

One common example is trivial JDBC programming. Dynamic classloading is used to load the driver class

If you see any code with Class.forName() then that is the example for dynamic loading

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, whenever your program will use classes that aren't necessarily available at compile time. An example would be a plug-in system, where you could create new plug-ins without recompiling the original application.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using reflection and creating new instances. You can always fetch new jar eg. via url and create object from it on runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Most common case in Java are plugins and plugin like libraries like JDBC drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic loading is a technique for programmatically invoking the functions of a class loader at run time. Let us look at how to load classes dynamically by using Class.forName (String className); method, it is a static method.

The above static method returns the class object associated with the class name. The string className can be supplied dynamically at run time. Once the class is dynamically loaded the class.newInstance () method returns an instance of the loaded class. It is just like creating a class object with no arguments.

A ClassNotFoundException is thrown when an application tries to load in a class through its class name, but no definition for the class with the specified name could be found.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example of dynamic class loading:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

interface IRobot{
    void start();
}


class Robot implements IRobot{
    public void start(){
        System.out.println("Starting robot...");
    }
}

public class Hello{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ClassLoader loader = Hello.class.getClassLoader();

        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.print("Enter class name to load: ");
            String className = scanner.nextLine();

            // Load the class dynamically.
            Class cls = loader.loadClass(className);
            IRobot obj =(IRobot) cls.newInstance();
            obj.start();

            scanner.close();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Class not found");
        } catch (Exception ex){
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            System.out.println("Exception occured.");

        }
    }
}
```